# Visual Studio Debugging problems when diagnosing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

So I've stumbled into a problem, after writing a framework for handling GUI stuff and its finally beginning to get done, I did a quick check on performance and its hogging up ~20% CPU. Its only running one thread which has a message loop with a render function. All Input etc for the GUI is handled by the messages sent via an event system.

I tried using the "Diagnostic Tools" with the CPU option checked, however the result just shows "exe name.exe" as the function, meaning I can't really find which function is hogging the most CPU.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Bumparonies still need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't a problem regarding optimizing, it was something faulty when launching the application via Visual studio (Even with Debugging disabled & release mode)

When launching it from the output directory it ran fine.

<_<